# QOS options of Plus Managed switches applicable to internet connection bandwidth?

Tags: networking, router, qos

I'm thinking of getting some Netgear plug switches for my home network as I wanted to use QoS options to prioritise certain ports for network traffic.

However I can't seem to get the answer if this QoS only applies to the internal LAN, to be used in offices that are maxing out their gigabit ports and need to make sure there is room for their VOIP calls etc - or if applicable to my internet connection.

I only have a very slow 4mbps internet connection and if I download anything it'll max the connection out at about 550kbps. Then time critical applications such as my VOIP calls, and Fem-To-Cell phone signal etc, eg low bandwidth but time critical devices suffer. So I was hoping I could give them critical bandwidth priority and put my download server as background so it would give way to them, but again I don't know if this just applies to general internal LAN bandwidth or if I can use it control what gets sent to the modem...

Comment: QoS can work within your network, and it can work with traffic exiting your network. It can't do anything about traffic coming into your network, until the traffic is already in your network.

Comment: Thanks Ron - so it can do what I want? Eg if i'm downloading something which is maxing my connection out at 550kbps, and I want my make a VOIP call it will make sure the VOIP uses all the bandwidth it needs from the 550kbps to work ok and throttle the download back whilst its in use?

Comment: A download is incoming traffic. If it clogs the inbound bandwidth QoS can't do anything. You can't do anything about incoming traffic, other than have your application tell the other side to stop sending. Your router can control what is sent, but it has no control over what it receives.

Comment: Hmm, what I was hoping you'd be able to do is tell it what your max internet bandwidth was and then what priority things were to be treated in so that a low priority device could only use the full 550kbps is nothing with a higher priority was trying to request the bandwidth. That seems to make sense to me, it doesn't really matter what the incoming data is, its throttling based on usage.

Comment: You can throttle outbound traffic, that's easy, but the inbound bandwidth is already used before your router even gets the traffic. The upstream router would need to throttle your inbound traffic. Your router can drop the traffic as soon as it sees it, but that is too late since the bandwidth was already used.

Comment: I definitely understand what you're saying Ron, the modem is outside of the switches network so how could it possibly control the data coming to it. What I was hoping though is that the internet network could know the internet bandwidth and throttle back certain ports based on demand from other services - the way I can throttle my download manager to whatever kbps download speed I want to allow bandwidth for other services on the network - but I guess the switches can't do this.

Comment: This is what your router is meant to do. Your modem simply queues any packets it gets until it can send them out to the ISP's RAS, first in first out. Its the routers job to apply prioritization. A good router will allow you to configure WAN QoS lanes, you can mark VOIP ports as high priority and everything else(default lane) as low priority. This should help stabilize it a bit. Your LAN is many times faster than WAN so internal QoS shouldnt matter unless you do large file moves within the LAN.